# Can't start opera driver in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, opera, operadriver

My problem is this: 
I run the opera driver and get the following error.
could you help me figure out how to deal with this?

Opera version 62.0.3331.116
Opera driver version 75.0.3770.100
Selenium version 3.141.59

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.opera.driver", "lib/driver/operadriver.exe");
    currentDriver = new OperaDriver();

org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: No matching capabilities found
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'TKSE-ESA0002', ip: '10.36.130.20', os.name: 'Windows Server 2012 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: driver.version: OperaDriver
remote stacktrace: Backtrace:
Ordinal0 [0x00007FF647C3CAB2+1952434]
Ordinal0 [0x00007FF647B77E42+1146434]
Ordinal0 [0x00007FF647AEF325+586533]
Ordinal0 [0x00007FF647A9257A+206202]
Ordinal0 [0x00007FF647A92C01+207873]
Ordinal0 [0x00007FF647A90ADF+199391]
Ordinal0 [0x00007FF647A74902+84226]
Ordinal0 [0x00007FF647A75A5E+88670]
GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF647DABA37+1351223]
GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF647CEF0FA+578810]
GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF647CEEE71+578161]
Ordinal0 [0x00007FF647C494FC+2004220]
GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF647CEF8D5+580821]
Ordinal0 [0x00007FF647B8D89E+1235102]
Ordinal0 [0x00007FF647B99F66+1285990]
Ordinal0 [0x00007FF647B98E8D+1281677]
BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFFED1213F2+34]
RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFFEF9154F4+52]
```

Comment: Unfortunately its open bug https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver/issues/71 with no solution (75.0.3770.100)

Answer (score 0):

chanded opera version to 60 and operadriver to 2.45 
it works